# App health checks - should they be dependent on infra components?

Tags: go, kubernetes, microservices

I am implementing a new service which connects to a queue and a database. Question: should my application health checks be disabled if my service is unable to talk to my database/queue (both/either)? In other words, should my application health checks be dependent on infrastructure components which are critical components ?
NB: I wanted to ensure my application doesn't abruptly restarts itself. I understand this is a mundane question, but really wanted fresh views.
Critical/suggestive comments both are welcome.

Currently, I have implemented plain old health checks, always green no matter what.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if the service cannot perform the desired functionality without the Queue or Database, then the health check should be failed.

For example, in kubernetes it allows to define a “Readiness Probe” and “Livenes Probe” based on health check endpoints. In your case, a health check based on availability of Queue or Database., the readiness probe will not allow any traffic in, while the liveness probe check if the service is alive, otherwise restart the pod.

Comment: thanks for reply @wpnpeiris, i totally agree with your answer.

Answer (score 0):

@wpnpeiris answer is certainly correct, but it would be useful to add a little more information.

You don't need to worry about a service "abruptly restarting".  You can configure the liveness probe with a "failure count", which means that the liveness probe will only report that it has failed if the internal liveness probe failed "failure count" times in a row.

Comment: thanks for reply @David M.Karr, fair point.